# Optaplanner: How to wait at depot to match time window for visit later in the day?

Tags: optaplanner

I have followed the example for CVRPTW in optaplanners source tree and it works great. :)

But I have a thing related to my use case I struggle with.

Let's say a Vehicle only has 2 Visits during a day and that visit A is available all day while Visit B has a narrow time window in the afternoon. Currently my best solution would become for the vehicle to leave early to service Visit A and the arrive much too early at Visit B - and wait until time window begins.

Instead I would want the Vehicle to wait at the depot instead so he has less need for waiting in the field.

At the Visit arrivalTime I have registered a listener in order to update arrivalTime.

```
@CustomShadowVariable(variableListenerClass = ArrivalTimeUpdatingVariableListener.class,
            sources = {
                @CustomShadowVariable.Source(variableName = "previousLocation")})
    public int getArrivalTime() {
        return arrivalTime;
    }

    public void setArrivalTime(int arrivalTime) {
        this.arrivalTime = arrivalTime;
    }
```

My listener currently looks like this:

```
public class ArrivalTimeUpdatingVariableListener implements VariableListener<Visit> {

    @Override
    public void beforeEntityAdded(ScoreDirector scoreDirector, Visit entity) {
        // Do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void afterEntityAdded(ScoreDirector scoreDirector, Visit visit) {
        updateArrivalTime(scoreDirector, visit);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeVariableChanged(ScoreDirector scoreDirector, Visit entity) {
        // Do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void afterVariableChanged(ScoreDirector scoreDirector, Visit visit) {
        updateArrivalTime(scoreDirector, visit);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeEntityRemoved(ScoreDirector scoreDirector, Visit entity) {
        // Do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void afterEntityRemoved(ScoreDirector scoreDirector, Visit entity) {
        // Do nothing
    }

    protected void updateArrivalTime(ScoreDirector scoreDirector, Visit sourceVisit) {
        WorkPlanSolution solution = (WorkPlanSolution) scoreDirector.getWorkingSolution();
        Location previousLocation = sourceVisit.getPreviousLocation();
        Integer departureTime = null;
        if(previousLocation != null) {
            departureTime = previousLocation.getDepartureTime();
        }
        Visit shadowVisit = sourceVisit;

        Integer arrivalTime = calculateArrivalTime(solution, shadowVisit, departureTime);
        while (shadowVisit != null && !Objects.equals(shadowVisit.getArrivalTime(), arrivalTime)) {
            scoreDirector.beforeVariableChanged(shadowVisit, "arrivalTime");
            shadowVisit.setArrivalTime(arrivalTime);
            scoreDirector.afterVariableChanged(shadowVisit, "arrivalTime");
            departureTime = shadowVisit.getDepartureTime();
            shadowVisit = shadowVisit.getNextVisit();
            arrivalTime = calculateArrivalTime(solution, shadowVisit, departureTime);
        }
    }

    private Integer calculateArrivalTime(WorkPlanSolution solution, Visit visit, Integer previousDepartureTime) {
        if (visit == null || visit.getLocation()== null) {
            return 0;
        }

        int distanceToPreviousInSeconds = 0;

        if(visit.getPreviousLocation() != null) {
            distanceToPreviousInSeconds = solution.getDistanceMatrix().getDistanceBetween(visit.getPreviousLocation().getLocation(), 
                    visit.getLocation());
        } else if(visit.getWorkPlan() != null) {
            distanceToPreviousInSeconds = solution.getDistanceMatrix().getDistanceBetween(visit.getWorkPlan().getLocation(), visit.getLocation());
        }

        int distanceToPreviousInMinutes = distanceToPreviousInSeconds / 60;  

        if (previousDepartureTime == null) {
            // PreviousStandstill is the Vehicle, so we leave from the Depot at the best suitable time

            return Math.max(visit.getReadyTime(), distanceToPreviousInMinutes);
        } else {
            return previousDepartureTime + distanceToPreviousInMinutes;
        }
    }
}
```

I am thinking, when updating the arrivalTime, I somehow need to detect if it is the first Visit that is being updated and then calculate the day backwards to find a suitable departure time taking all ready-times from time windows into account.

But this must be a general issue. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I finally managed to solve it, although I still need to optimize for performance.

In semi-pseudo terms this is what I did in my updateArrivalTime method:

```
protected void updateArrivalTime(ScoreDirector scoreDirector, Visit sourceVisit) {
        WorkPlanSolution solution = (WorkPlanSolution) scoreDirector.getWorkingSolution();
    Location previousLocation = sourceVisit.getPreviousLocation();
    WorkPlan plan = getWorkPlan(sourceVisit);
    Integer prevDepartureTime = null;

    if (previousLocation != null) {
        prevDepartureTime = previousLocation.getDepartureTime();
    }


    if(plan == null) {
        // No plan found. Just update from this element and downwards
        Visit firstLink = sourceVisit;
        Integer arrivalTime = calculateArrivalTime(solution, plan, firstLink, prevDepartureTime);
        updateChainedArrival(scoreDirector, solution, arrivalTime, plan, firstLink);
    } else {
        // Plan found. Recalculate from the beginning of the workplan.
        plan.resetDepartureTime();
        Visit firstLink = plan.getNextVisit();
        Integer arrivalTime = calculateArrivalTime(solution, plan, firstLink, plan.getDepartureTime());
        updateChainedArrival(scoreDirector, solution, arrivalTime, plan, firstLink);

        // Update wait time if needed 
        int trimableTime = WorkPlanHelper.calculateTrimableWaitTime(plan);
        if(trimableTime > 0) {
            // Update all arrival times of the workplan again
            firstLink = plan.getNextVisit();
            plan.setDepartureTime(plan.getDepartureTime() + trimableTime);
            arrivalTime = calculateArrivalTime(solution, plan, firstLink, plan.getDepartureTime());
            updateChainedArrival(scoreDirector, solution, arrivalTime, plan, firstLink);
        }
    }

}
```

How it work is that `WorkPlanHelper.calculateTrimableWaitTime(plan);` can figure out how many minutes departure from depot can be delayed in order to minimize wait time at each customer but without overruling time windows.

Answer (score 0):

If a visit is the first customer (so `if previousStandstill instanceof Vehicle`) then the arrivalTime should indeed be `max(readyTime, previousStandstillWhichIsVehicle.getDepotOpenTime() + drivingTime)`.

The rest is like in the example: when the arrivalTime of a visit changes (and therfore it's departureTime too), the listener iterates over the rest of the chain to updates those visits accordingly (see also image in the docs).

Comment: Thanx. My use case is a bit more tricky. In the mentioned example Customer/Visit A is available all day and Visit B only in the afternoon. The depot opens in the morning and closes in the evening. Because Visit A is available as soon as the depot opens, the calculated solution is to go to A immediately(ready time is before depot opens) and then on to B - only to wait until the time window for B opens in the afternoon. But best solution would be to spend that waiting time at the depot in the morning.